# r plot not changing color

Tags: r, plot

The plot function inherited from a r library `qgcomp` is not changing color, line width or adding title.

Here's an reproducible example.

```
install.packages("qgcomp", dependencies = TRUE)
library(qgcomp)

# using data from the qgcomp package
data("metals", package="qgcomp")

Xnm <- c(
  'arsenic','barium','cadmium','calcium','chromium','copper',
  'iron','lead','magnesium','manganese','mercury','selenium','silver',
  'sodium','zinc'
)


# continuous outcome
results <- qgcomp.boot(y~.,dat=metals[,c(Xnm, 'y')], 
                       family=gaussian(),
                       q=4, B=1000)

print(results)

plot(results, lwd=4, col="blue")
```

It is still showing me the plot with default color and line thickness. Any help on how to change the line thickness, color and size of x, y axis is much appreciated.
[image]

Answer (score 3):

These plots are made with {ggplot2} I believe, which is why the "usual" `plot()` arguments aren't doing anything. You can see the plot function help with `?qgcomp:::plot.qgcompfit`. From inspecting the function, it unfortunately looks like some of these design choices have been hard-coded. You can edit some of the properties by updating the defaults using `ggplot2`. For example, to update the linewidth:

```r
library(ggplot2)
update_geom_defaults("line", aes(linewidth = 2))
plot(results)
```

[image: linechart]

If you also set `suppressprint = TRUE` inside the plot function, it returns a ggplot2 object so you can override the scale functions used and add a title in the normal way:

```r
p <- plot(results, suppressprint = TRUE) 
p + ggtitle("Title") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("red")) +
  theme_classic(base_size = 20)
```

[image: edited chart]

Comment: Nice one. For the sake of completion, markers and error bars can be customized via the color scale, i. e. by adding (example) ` scale_color_manual(values = c('blue', 'red', 'green'))`.

Comment: @nrennie , one last request, somehow I am unable to get the error bar size, shape and color to change, this is what I tried `update_geom_defaults("errorbars", list(linetype=1, size=3, color="green")` any suggestions ??

Comment: @I_O, one lingering question above

Comment: You can recolor confidence band and error bars (as shown in above answer and comment) by overwriting the existing scales (`scale_fill_manual(...)`, `scale_color_manual`). You can, uniformly, tweak errorbar linetype by, e. g., `update_geom_defaults("errorbar", aes(linewidth = 2, lty = 3))` *before you replot* the object.